# Can't save custom Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I need to save these 2 models. I train them in the same seq2seq model but use them separately.

```
h_size = 512
emb_size = 64

class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, name='lstm1_enc')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_enc')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_enc')
        
    def call(self, x):
        state = []
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(x)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        
        return state
    

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_len, emb_size, name='embed')
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm1_dec')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_dec')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_dec')
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_len, activation='softmax', name='fc')
        
    def call(self, x, init_state):
        state = []
        out = self.embed(x)
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out, initial_state=init_state[2])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out, initial_state=init_state[1])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(out, initial_state=init_state[0])
        state.append((h, c))
        out = self.fc(out)
        
        return out, state
```

But when I save them like this:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(seq2seq, 'seq2seq', save_traces=False, overwrite=True)
tf.keras.models.save_model(encoder_model, 'encoder', save_traces=False, overwrite=True)
tf.keras.models.save_model(decoder_model, 'decoder', save_traces=False, overwrite=True)
```

I have this error when loading them:

```
encoder_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('encoder')
decoder_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('decoder')

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, random_vector_len))
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, ))

enc_state = encoder_model(encoder_inputs)
decoder_outputs, _ = decoder_model(decoder_inputs, enc_state)

seq2seq = tf.keras.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

seq2seq.summary()
encoder_model.summary()
decoder_model.summary()
```

> ValueError: Cannot call custom layer encoder_4 of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.load.Encoder'>, because the call function was not serialized to the SavedModel.Please try one of the following methods to fix this issue:

> (1) Implement `get_config` and `from_config` in the layer/model class, and pass the object to the `custom_objects` argument when loading the model. For more details, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

> (2) Ensure that the subclassed model or layer overwrites `call` and not `__call__`. The input shape and dtype will be automatically recorded when the object is called, and used when saving. To manually specify the input shape/dtype, decorate the call function with `@tf.function(input_signature=...)`.

I'm using TensorFlow-gpu v2.5.
I don't use custom layers internally, tried adding layers from **init** in get_config but nothing helped

Comment: Exactly as the error message informs you, you need to implement the instance method `get_config()` and the class method `from_config()` if you are using a custom model class.  See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving for details.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save and load custom models, you need to define how they're serialized and deserialized.
The error message links to the [relevant documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving#custom_objects).

**In TensorFlow v2.13.0+:**

The simplest way to do this is by applying the `tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()` decorator to your custom object and creating a `get_config()` function within returning a dictionary that contains the variables needed to be saved.

So your encoder and decoder should look like this:

```py
# clears all previously registered custom objects
tf.keras.saving.get_custom_objects().clear()


# upon registration, you can optionally specify a package or a name
# if left blank, the package defaults to `Custom` and the name defaults to the class name
@tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, name='lstm1_enc')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_enc')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_enc')
        
    def call(self, x):
        state = []
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(x)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        
        return state

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            "lstm1": self.lstm1,
            "lstm2": self.lstm2,
            "lstm3": self.lstm3
        }


@tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_len, emb_size, name='embed')
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm1_dec')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_dec')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_dec')
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_len, activation='softmax', name='fc')
        
    def call(self, x, init_state):
        state = []
        out = self.embed(x)
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out, initial_state=init_state[2])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out, initial_state=init_state[1])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(out, initial_state=init_state[0])
        state.append((h, c))
        out = self.fc(out)
        
        return out, state

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            "embed": self.embed,
            "lstm1": self.lstm1,
            "lstm2": self.lstm2,
            "lstm3": self.lstm3,
            "fc": self.fc
        }
```

Then you can simply save and load the models as you've already done.

##### Before TensorFlow v2.13.0:

Here, you need to enable the `save_tracing` parameter when saving the model.

For the encoder, this would look like

```py
encoder.save(MODEL_PATH, save_traces=True, overwrite=True)

# which is an equivalent but more concise version of
tf.keras.models.save_model(encoder, MODEL_PATH, save_traces=True, overwrite=True)
```

`save_traces` is set to True by default, so the parameter can simply be omitted, which leaves you with

```py
encoder.save(MODEL_PATH, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: I am using an earlier version of tensorflow and there is no such decorator there. Is there any analog of this decorator in tensorflow 2.5?